# How can I remove all whitespace from string?

Tags: c#

I've tried following code:

```
foreach (string item in strArr)
{
    item.Replace(" ", "");
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(foldercreationPATH.Text + "\\final\\" + item);
};
```

but it doesn't do anything. If I add return before item.Replace, then it throws errors:

> Method must have a return type
>   and
>   return must not be followed by an object expression!

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: string.Replace. Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode character or String in the current string are replaced with another specified Unicode character or String. RDFM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign your variable with the new value.

```
item = item.Replace(" ", "");
```

Or just put the Replace inside the method.

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(foldercreationPATH.Text + "\\final\\" + item.Replace(" ", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.

```
var item = item.trim();
```

Comment: Sorry but `var item = item.trim();` won't work.  The `var` is not needed since `item` has been declared already.

Comment: This only removes leading and trailing whitespace. I think the OP is looking to remove all whitespace, even if its in the middle of the string.